# Django Admin Model - Foreign key is showing email, not id

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have two models -
An Article Model.
A Reporter Model.

Just like the Django Documentation

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.email)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.headline)
```

I also have registered this in my admin.py file

```
@admin.register(Reporter)
class ReporterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


@admin.register(Article)
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

When I go to add an article in admin, the field for reporter shows me the reporters email, I want it to show me the reporters id (the id field that is created by default).

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

```
class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.email)
```

Should be

```
class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```